# Why Is My React Bootstrap CSS Not Working?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I literally threw away all my code just to isolate the issue and fix it, but it didnt work and the css is not showing

(main file)
index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './App'

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

App.js

```
   import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table'
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Table striped bordered hover>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Username</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>Mark</td>
                        <td>Otto</td>
                        <td>@mdo</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>Jacob</td>
                        <td>Thornton</td>
                        <td>@fat</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td colSpan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
                        <td>@twitter</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        )
    }
}
export default App
```

.                                                                                                                    .
Any help appreciated, i just want to use bootstrap css in my app

my path and folders:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What i did in this same case, is to install normal bootstrap package and import the default styles from your sass file.

```
@import '../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```